# Java what does "<<" mean?

Tags: java, syntax

```
int x = 1 << 25;
```

What does the "<<" mean?
Unsure of what this does, my ide gives me no errors though..
I've tried looking on forums and googling but could not find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: [Java Bitshift operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: Also for future reference you can use SymbolHound (a search engine) that allows you to search without stripping symbols. For example [this](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3C+java) would be your search/results for this particular question

Answer (score 2):

It's a left (bit) shift. [JLS-15.19. Shift operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) says (in part)

> The operators `<<` (left shift), `>>` (signed right shift), and `>>>` (unsigned right shift) are called the shift operators. The left-hand operand of a shift operator is the value to be shifted; the right-hand operand specifies the shift distance.

For a simple example, consider

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << 1));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << 2));
```

Which outputs

```
1
10
100
```

as it shifts the single `1` bit left once and twice respectively.

In your example, `int x = 1 << 25;` that is a `1` followed by 25 `0`s (in binary, or `33554432` in decimal).